# Complex number roots problem

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Can anyone help me with this? Please.(fix: the function is multivalued)

$$Z=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{1+\sqrt {3}i}\right)^{10}$$   $$\to Z^{\frac{1}{4}}=?$$

Hey everyone!

I'm an electrical engineering freshman, and I'm new to this website. But something tells me you will see hell of a lot of me around here.

Comment: Where is the `complex` part of the question?

Comment: You tagged this with "complex-numbers", so I'm wondering if you meant to have some $i$'s in your expression.

Comment: Sorry I just fixed it

Comment: How do you define $z^{1/4}$ when $z$ is complex?

Comment: Well, when z is complex you can't define $\sqrt[4]{z}$ but you can define $z^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ***how*** you define it. What is $(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ for example?

Comment: I know this sounds awkward. I asked the same question but professor told me this.

Comment: You'll need to clear that up with your professor, then. The equation $z^4+1=0$ has 4 complex roots. Any of them could be called $(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ since for each root $z^4 = -1$ (then you need to decide which one to choose). Or maybe you mean to consider $z^{\frac{1}{4}}$ as a multivalued function, then the answer would be the set of all 4 roots. Either way, that should be spelled out in the question.

Comment: Yup, it is a multivalued function, i shoud've mentioned it. my bad.

Comment: It would be better to edit the question and add the clarification in there, rather than leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple approach would be to simplify $\frac {1-i\sqrt 3}{1+i\sqrt 3}$, multiplying top and bottom by the complex conjugate.
This will give you a complex number in standard Cartesian form.  Then convert it to polar form.  Then apply deMoivres theorem.

The fancy way to do it would be to say: $1+i\sqrt 3 = 2e^{\frac \pi3i}$ and $1-i\sqrt 3 = 2e^{-i\frac \pi3}$

Their ratio is: $e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}$

$(e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i})^{10} =(e^{\frac {20\pi}{3}i}) = (e^{6\pi i})(e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}) = (e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}) $

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$Z=\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{1+i \sqrt {3}} \cdot \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{1-i \sqrt {3}}\right)^{10} = \frac{(1-i\sqrt{3})^{20}}{4^{10}}$$

---

[ EDIT  (after some clarifications in the comments under the original question) ]    From:

$$Z=\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{20} = \left(\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{5}\right)^4$$

it is clear that $z = \left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{5}$ satisfies $z^4 = Z$, so $z$ is one of the values of $Z^{\frac{1}{4}}$. The other 3 values are $z \cdot \omega_1$, $z \cdot \omega_2$, $z \cdot \omega_3$ where $\omega_k = e^{i\, 2 k \pi / 4}$ $\;|\;\; k=1,2,3$ are the non-unit 4th [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), so in the end the solution set is $\{z, z \cdot i, -z, -z \cdot i\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Convert $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{1+\sqrt{3}i} \right)$ to polar coordinate.